# flask wait function certain time for accepting data

Tags: python, flask

I am programing a QR authentication pdf printing system using flask.
So I get a problem with that.
In hear I compare the generate QR code with the user input Qr code.
If both matches do the print function vise versa.

After generating the QR code it shows on the webpage. Then the user can get a photo and it should show it to the raspberry pi camera. Then it decodes the QR code using OpenCV and sends it back to the flask server.

this is my code up to now

python file

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    global qr_cv     # get from raspberry pi
    global qrdata    # generate from flask

    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return flask.render_template("index.html")

    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        if qrdata != qr_cv:
            return flask.render_template("oops.html")

        if (qrdata == qr_cv):
            # Print Function

            return flask.render_template("printed.html")

        return flask.render_template("index.html")
```

HTML file

```
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data">
    <input type=file name=file">
    <input type=submit value=Print">
</form>
```

So my question is when I press the **Print** button flask should search for the certain time for the **qr_cv** data because the user had to get a photo of the QR code and go to the raspberry pi camera and show it to it. After showing it will send the data to the flask server.

This code suddenly renders the **oops.html** file because initially **qr_cv** send nothing.

So, I need any help from you and I highly appreciate your suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: aside: I'm not sure `return flask.render_template("index.html")` is ever accessible

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It's not an issue yet @anon01